# How much $\rm D_2O$ is in Earth's icepacks?

Tags: hydrogen, geophysics, ice, isotopes, chemical-compounds

How much $\rm D_2O$, by mass and/or percentage, is locked in Earth's polar icepacks?  Is the $\rm D_2O$:$\rm H_2O$ ratio the same as elsewhere?

Comment: See [this](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/7079/how-different-is-the-proportion-of-heavy-water-ce2h2o-in-the-different-o) post on earthscience.SE.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the [Earth Science site](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: While I don't know the answer to the first question, I do know that precipitation in polar regions tends to be depleted of deuterium compared to precipitation in equatorial regions;  so I would imagine that the Antarctic ice sheet has a relatively low abundance of deuterium compared to the Earth average.  See [here](https://wateriso.utah.edu/waterisotopes/media/IsoMaps/jpegs/h_Global/Hma_Global.jpg) for a map of the distribution and [here](https://wateriso.utah.edu/waterisotopes/pages/information/background.html) for a brief discussion of why isotope distributions vary geographically.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected this was the wrong SE, but didn't know about the [EarthScience SE](https://EarthScience.stackexchdnge.com/). Since the comments on my question pointed me to the resources I sought, I'm answering my own question and closing it with "Answered by the endlessly helpful SE community. See the comments for details." Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\require{mhchem}$ Very most of [deuterium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium) in water or ice forms $\ce{HDO}$ ($\ce{H-O-D}$), with the ratio $$\frac{\ce{D2O}}{\ce{HDO}} \approx \frac{\ce{HDO}}{\ce{H2O}}$$

as the ratios are given by deuterium relative abundance approx $0.0156\ \%$, what means about $0.031\ \%\ \ce{HDO}$.

There is ongoing very quickly established chemical equilibrium in liquid water:

$$\ce{H2O + D2O <=> 2 HDO}$$

with statistically determined equilibrium constant

$$K = \frac{[\ce{HDO}]^2}{[\ce{H2O}][\ce{D2O}]} \approx 4$$

It means if we mixed $\ce{D2O}$ and $\ce{H2O}$ in molar ratio $1:1$, deuterium would very quickly redistribute itself in molar ratios $\ce{D2O} : \ce{HDO}  : \ce{H2O}\quad  1 : 2 : 1$

There are very slight variances in deuterium abundance, based on temperature at forming of condensed phases. But it is more prominent for $\ce{^{18}O}/\ce{^{16}O}$ than for $\ce{D}/\ce{H}$, as the former has bigger influence on relative mass change of $\ce{H2O}$ molecule.

$$M(\ce{H2{^{16}O}}) \approx \text{18 g/mol}$$

$$M(\ce{HD{^{16}O}}) \approx \text{19 g/mol}$$

$$M(\ce{H2{^{18}O}}) \approx \text{20 g/mol}$$